# In version 1.3.3 of WikkaWiki, why does the install script fail to create database tables?

Tags: mysql, wiki

When I run the auto-install script for a new installation of v1.3.3, I get a the following message indicating that none of the tables for the database were installed:

> Creating page table... FAILED: Already exists?

I have verified that I provided the correct database credentials and that the database user has create table privileges.

I am running mysql version: `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing around with the mysql create table statements in the `setup/install.php` script, I discovered the issue. My version of mysql doesn't like the following syntax for declaring the engine type:

```
TYPE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

I replaced `TYPE` with `ENGINE` in all the mysql queries in this script and the script was able to create all the database tables.

It appears that in MySQL 5.1, support for the `TYPE` keyword was finally removed.

Comment: Here is the corresponding issue in WikkaWiki's tracker: https://wush.net/trac/wikka/ticket/1049